# I don't get squaring loop index in prime number function

Tags: javascript

Below are my functions that sum up all prime numbers that are below a given `maxNum`.

I don't understand why the for loop in the `isPrime` function doesn't work when using `j <= num` instead of `j ** 2 <= num`.

```js
function sumPrimes(maxNum) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 2; i <= maxNum; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i
        }
    }
    return sum
}

function isPrime(num) {
    for (let j = 2; j <= num; j++) { // when I use j ** 2 <= num it works
        if (num % j === 0) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

console.log(sumPrimes(20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `j <= num`, the loop will count `j` up to the number itself and then it would match `num % j === 0` and return false.

So if `num` was 17, the loop would be executed with `17 <= 17` which passes and the loop body executes `17 % 17 === 0` so it always returns false, no matter what number you pass in.

you could use `j < num` instead of `j <= num` in the loop head which should also work because the number itself is never reached when using the smaller than sign.